# XML 1.0 restrictions on complex types

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to place a restriction on an element which has a complex type:

XML:

```
        <longName lang="eng_us">An example longName goes here! </longName>
```

I'd like to add restrictions in the XSD longName as well as lang. I am able to do this for simple elements, but having issues validating this one. Here is my XSD for the above:

XSD:

```
<xs:element name="longName">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="lang" />
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
```

This is the restriction I would like to add to longName and lang:

```
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                <xs:minLength value="1" />
                                <xs:maxLength value="254" />
                            </xs:restriction>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it in two stages.  First declare a top-level `simpleType` with the restriction you require

```
<xs:simpleType name="longNameContent">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:minLength value="1" />
    <xs:maxLength value="254" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Then make the `complexType` an extension of this:

```
<xs:element name="longName">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="longNameContent">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="lang" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

If your schema has a `targetNamespace` then you'll need to bind a prefix to that namespace in the schema document and use the prefix on the type, i.e.

```
<xs:schema ....
           targetNamespace="http://example.com"
           xmlns:tns="http://example.com">
```

and then

```
<xs:simpleContent>
  <xs:extension base="tns:longNameContent">
```